# How do I make a column showing the length of a string from another column?

Tags: r

A sample of my dataframe where the first line is the column title:

```
col1
some string
some other string
```

How do I make another column showing how long each of col1's strings are?

Comment: Did you mean `nchar(df$col1)#[1] 11 17`
`

Comment: To expand on @akrun 's answer:   `df[,2] <- nchar(df[,1])`  (not tested - you may want to create a name for the new column)

Comment: @akrun When I run that in the console, I get the error `'nchar()' requires a character vector`

Comment: @Username I think you have a `factor` column as `nchar(factor(df$col1))#
Error in nchar(factor(df$col1)) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector`
 Convert to character class. `nchar(as.character(df$col1))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it thanks to akrun's help:

```
df$col2 <- nchar(as.character(df$col1))
```